# search in sqlite database c++

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

First of all this is my full code:

```
/*Getting user input and checking it using sqlite*/
string data, sql;
int id, rc;
int al;
do {
    cout << "Enter your id:";
    cin >> id;
} while (id > 9999999999 || id < 1000000000);
/*Creating a sqlite3 pointer in order to connect to the sql*/
sqlite3* connection = nullptr;
/*opening sql*/
int result = sqlite3_open("sql.db", &connection);
/*Creating a query to search sql*/
if (result) {
    cerr << "Error open DB " << sqlite3_errmsg(connection) << std::endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Opened Database Successfully!" << std::endl;
}
sqlite3* query = nullptr;
/*Searching database for id*/
data = ("CALLBACK FUNCTION");
sql = ("SELECT * FROM Doctors WHERE nationalCode = " + to_string(id) + " ;");
/*start searching*/
/*if sql found a document, then it will continue; else, it will make a new document then 
it will continue*/
rc = sqlite3_exec(connection, sql.c_str(), callback, (void*)data.c_str(), NULL);

if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
    cout << "Operation OK!" << endl;
    cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
    cout << "1:making a Visit" << endl;
    cout << "2:cancel your Visit" << endl;
    cout << "3:edit your Information" << endl;
    cout << "4:delete your Account" << endl;
    cin >> al;
    switch (al)
    {
    case 1:
        createVisit();
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Hello";
        break;
    case 3:
        editDoctor();
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Hello";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Wrong number, Closing the Application";
        break;
    }
}
else {
    cout << "we can't find your information! Creating a new document right now" << endl
        << "+______________________________________________________________________________+" << endl;
    sqlite3_close(connection);
    createDoctor();
}
sqlite3_close(connection);
```

My problem is with these lines:

```
data = ("CALLBACK FUNCTION");
sql = ("SELECT * FROM Doctors WHERE nationalCode = " + to_string(id) + " ;");
/*start searching*/
/*if sql found a document, then it will continue; else, it will make a new document then 
it will continue*/
rc = sqlite3_exec(connection, sql.c_str(), callback, (void*)data.c_str(), NULL);
```

I have a sqlite database and it's connected to my console app correctly but, when I'm searching for user input in the rows, no matter what it will run the if statement. I want to check if the user input is available. If the user input was available, run the **if** statement and if the user input was not available, then run the **else** statement.

I believe there is something run with the "rc". Can someone show me a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3_exec` will return `SQLITE_OK` if the SQL was successfully executed, regardless of whether any rows were returned. You need to use the callback to process the results of the query.

For more information, see [the documentation of that function](https://sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_exec), and of the rest of the SQLite API.